# Why am I getting a blank object, even if it exists in the database pdo?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm getting a blank `obj` despite the fact that the `search` `element` exists in the `database`.

**here is what I'm trying**

```
   $userInput = 'john';
   $db = getDB();
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, email,  token FROM users WHERE  name LIKE name=:input";        
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("input", $userInput,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $usernameDetails = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  print_r($usernameDetails );
```

I'm not getting any kind of `error`.

Please help me.

Comment: So, decide do you need `LIKE` or do you need `=`?

Comment: i decided i would like `LIKE`

Comment: Then remove `=`. You know proper `LIKE` format, don't you?

Comment: @u_mulder, i tried different format of `LIKE` but  got `error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong syntax for `LIKE` operator

```
name LIKE name=:input";
```

You need to change this to

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT user_id, email,  token FROM users WHERE  name LIKE :input');
$query->bindParam("input", "%$userInput%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**Note :** `%` means any characters.

Comment: ya ravi i'm getting the result now, i tried @moulder answer as well but was getting some `error`

Comment: i have one doubt  does this query will fetch multiple results? right now i'm getting single result. could you please tell me how to `fetch` multiple `results`

Comment: @EaB What do you mean by mutiple result. That depends on data, if you have data, then you will get them in resultset

Comment: ya i'm getting the result with these statement `         $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $data = $stmt->fetchALl();`

Answer (score 0):

In your query you use a strange approach:

```
WHERE  name LIKE name=:input
```

`name` like what?

You either use

```
SELECT user_id, email,  token FROM users WHERE name=:input
```

or

```
SELECT user_id, email,  token FROM users WHERE name LIKE :input
```

In case of `LIKE` I suppose you need to add `%`, otherwise `LIKE` becomes `=`:

```
// previous code here
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("input", '%' . $userInput . '%' ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
// more code here
```